# Can't access docker-machine IP on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

I'm using Docker Terminal on Windows running a container from  my nginx image and when I access the docker-machine IP on my browser I get "CONNECTION_REFUSED".

This is command that I used to run the container

```
docker run -it -d -v /home/user/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 myimage
```

Comment: what is the command you used to run the container?

Comment: docker run -it -d -v /homer/user/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 myimage

Comment: Doesn't sound like a problem from your host side.  The fact that you're getting a connection refused message indicates to me that you are correctly pinging your container.  This sounds like something is wrong inside of your container.  Are you sure that nginx is running in the container?  Have you tried restarting with commands similar to `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`?

Comment: Well, it works removing the image from virtualbox and creating again the image and container. I really don't now what happened :(

Answer (score 0):

- Check if your container is running (`docker ps`)
- Log in your container to see if there is any error log (`docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash`)
- Make sure you are using correct IP address (`docker-machine ip container_name`)

Comment: I checked and yes, it's everything ok with container configuration. This problem started when I restarted my PC, the docker-machine just does not work. I only have one machine (default)

Comment: I guess `docker-machine ip container_name` doesn't exist, but `docker-machine ip`

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to check logs with `docker logs <container name>`

After that, you'll see if `connection refused` is due to a

- Address visibility problem.
- NginX configuration problem.
- Port 80 is already being used.
- ...